# maxOffsetsPerTrigger vs number of cores in the spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks

For example, my spark structured streaming application has Kafka as the message source, and below are the  details of the different configurations.

**Kafka setup**:

Message source: kafka

Partitions : 40

**input parameters**:

maxOffsetsPerTrigger : 1000

**Cluster setup**:

Number of workers = 5

Number of cores/worker = 8

**Question**:

With the above setup, does it read

(1000 * 5 * 8) = 40000 messages every time

or

(1000 * 5) = 5000 messages every time

or

read 1000 messages and distribute it across the 5 worker nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. *The specified total number of offsets will be **proportionally** split across topicPartitions of different volume*.

So it's the last option in your list, and each executor at maximum will process 200 offsets per trigger, split between individual cores (25 offsets/core).  But it could be smaller if you don't have enough data collected in the specific trigger period.

Also, in new versions of Spark, there are additional options, like, `minOffsetsPerTrigger` that will allow to process bigger batches in case if your trigger period didn't have enough data to process.